# Why is the * is not considered a MathSymbol?

Tags: c#

I was answering this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515852/what-exactly-is-classified-as-a-symbol-in-c/39515957#39515957) and one guy commented in the thread that the '*' nor the '-' are not MathSymbol. If you execute this c# both return false:

```
char.IsSymbol('*'); //false
char.IsSymbol('-'); //false
```

According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00k2wda1(v=vs.110).aspx) :

> Valid symbols are members of the following categories in
>   UnicodeCategory: MathSymbol, CurrencySymbol, ModifierSymbol, and
>   OtherSymbol. Symbols in the Unicode standard are a loosely defined set
>   of characters that include the following:

I did this [snippet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3ivTUx) to see all the MathSymbols and I found out that the asterisk nor the minus symbol were there, obviously.

```
      int ctr = 0;
      UnicodeCategory category = UnicodeCategory.MathSymbol;

      for (ushort codePoint = 0; codePoint < ushort.MaxValue; codePoint++) {
         Char ch = Convert.ToChar(codePoint);

         if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(ch) == category) {
            if (ctr % 5 == 0)
               Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("{0} (U+{1:X4})     ", ch, codePoint);
            ctr++;
         } 
      }
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("\n{0} characters are in the {1:G} category", 
                        ctr, category);
```

I'd like too know if there is a reason behind, why this 2 symbols are not considered MathSymbols?

Comment: [Unicode Math Symbols are listed here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sm/list.htm). Unless explicitly stated (which it is not), normal ASCII characters '*' and '-`' are not in this range.

Comment: That's only a math symbol to a programmer, not to a typographer.  People that set type have very high standards :)

Comment: So it doesn't matter what various programming languages use for mathematical operators (e.g. asterisk for multiplication).  "Math symbols" in this context are like the kind like you'd find on your high school math homework.

Comment: * is just a substitute because the math multiplication "×" will be confusing with x, but I am a bit surprised that - is not math minus.

Comment: ‘-’ is a hyphen, not a minus symbol. ‘−’ \u2212 is a minus symbol.

Comment: It's actually a hyphen-minus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Unicode Math Symbols are listed here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sm/list.htm).

Unless explicitly stated (which it is not) normal ASCII characters '*' and '-' and '/' are not in this range, even if they are conventionally used in text / programming languages to represent math operations.

Unlike the '+' character which is included in the "Symbol, Math" category, these other characters have more overloaded usages / names (eg. asterisk, dash-hyphen, solidus) which makes their inclusion as generalized mathematical dubious: a Unicode character belongs to a *single* category.

Answer (score 2):

Neither asterisk nor hyphen are math symbols, regardless of the fact that we typically use them and understand their meaning.

Unicode math symbols are things like `×`  (`&#215;` as a decimal escape)

Answer (score 2):

The primary use of `*` is as punctuation (an [asterisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk)) and `-` is used as a dash or hyphen.